# not full height vertical divider android

Tags: android, android-layout, divider

I already have a vertical divider between my two buttons like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_selector"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Connexion"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_selector"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Inscription"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

but I'd like to have one which doesn't take all the available height, but just half for example, starting at the middle of the layout. 
I already tried to create a custom divider :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="0.5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

and then to play with android:height, but it does nothing good. Any other ideas ?

Comment: In your Buttons, `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` must be `android:layout_width="0dp"`, if you want to take advantage of the LinearLayout's **weights**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks for the advice